# First time multiprocessing, having trouble getting it to run properly

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

Here is my code:

```
def feature(x):
    times = []
    for j in array:
        pat = x[x.id == j]
        min_dates_j = pat.groupby(["event_description"]).min()

        try:
            time = ((min_dates_j.loc["test1","event_description"] -  min_dates_j.loc["test2","event_description"]).days) 
        except:
            time = np.NaN()

        times.append(time)

        return times

from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(10)

times = p.map(feature, df)

feature_df["A"] = times
```

This code is taking a very long time to run so I'm attempting to use multiprocessing to expedite the compilation time. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've looked at the `pool` function I dont quite understand why it's not improving the performance.

EDIT:

I'd like to mention that my dataset contains 20494463 rows and my system has 16 cpus.

```
p = Pool(16)

times = p.map(feature, np.array_split(df,150))
```

Comment: Is it running and giving you correct results?

Comment: It hasn't even compiled fully yet. The code does work on a smaller sample set

Comment: Is it not *compiling*? I don't think that's what you mean. Can you test it with a small set and see if the multiprocessing works and gives you the correct results there? Also, I'm pretty sure this would throw a `NameError` with `array` in your function... Also, if `df` is a `pd.DataFrame`, then `map` will iterate over the *column names*.

Comment: Indeed, the way your function is written, I'm not sure you can even use `map`....

Comment: Hm, do you have any other recommendations? Sorry, this is brand new to me

Comment: I have no way to give any recommendations. I've tried to get you to clarify what your problem actually is, and you haven't answered my requests for clarification. More importantly, I have no idea *what* you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to pass a list of dataframes to map. and then you can concatenate those dataframes

Comment: @djk47463 So, instead of just having `df` as an input into `map()`, It should be a list of dataframes?

Comment: Thats how I usually use map, not sure how else to doit

Comment: @djk47463 take a look at my edits, what do you think of this approach?

Comment: Seems fine, is it faster? I’m quite sure you can make this code faster without multiprocessing first. However, you  would need to add a sample df, what is the array in the for loop. You should really re ask this question about how to do what you want properly, by adding examples.

Comment: I.e. why not just group by the values in the array, and what you are currently grouping by